# QGIS Geometry Generator not working for some features at some scales

Tags: qgis, labeling, polygon-creation, geometry-generator

I have a set of layers, one of them is labeled using geometry generator. Thing is, at some scales (1:800 and up) and some features (like 1/30) the geometry generator evalues to null geometry, so the feature is not labeled. I "fixed" it temporarily evaluating the resulting geometry and using another tye of label if it is null, but its not acceptable for printing. The Geometry Generator expression is

```
with_variable(
    'g',
    difference( 
        buffer($geometry,12),
        aggregate(
            layer:='ManzanasM',
            aggregate:='collect',
            expression:=$geometry)),
    if(buffer( @g,-5) is null,
        buffer(pole_of_inaccessibility($geometry,1),5),
        buffer( @g,-5)))
```

It makes a buffer of itself and then a difference between that buffer and the layer 'ManzanasM', so the resulting polygon is outside the block. Its a grose replacement of a "label outside polygon" feature that I know its now implemented, but I cannot install new QGis in my PC without a lot of bureaucracy.

The layer is part of an Atlas dependant layout, I dont know if that's affecting it, but I dont think so. Used the same expression in Symbology to visualize exactly what im labeling, and after I zoom out more than 1:800 the geometry dissapears (and is replaced by a circle, because that's my temporary solution).

In the image, its visible how the colored parts outside the blocks are the zones where i want my label to be. There are two geometries that are not correctly created in the lower left.

[image: Example]

EDIT:
Here are some example files. They need those custom expressions loaded.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XFJVQZfrADX92tnEe0Lz-k3AC9EGDFGA/view?usp=sharing

[image: Centered labels instead of outside polygon]

Comment: Geometry generator only renders expression-generated geometries when the geometry of the current feature (`$geometry`) is visible. Thus if you have  apoint layer and create a line from this point with geometry generator, the line disappears as soon as the point falls out of the map canvas, even if the line would continue to run over the canvas. Could somthing similar be the problem in your case?

Comment: Do the features where the label is not created correctly have geometry errors? I guess in your screenshot you speak about the block labeled 56 and 64 that are not correct, right? Can you provide sample data to test?

Comment: No, all features are visible. And this layer is virtual, generated on the fly. You made me think maybe thats an issue, im going to save the virtual layer and apply this style to it

Comment: I'm curious to hear if the virtual layer was the issue.

Comment: No it wasn't... Added sample files. Most expressions are not required but im not in mood for cherry picking... sorry :(

Comment: I loaded your data, 56 and 64 appear with the same style/label, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDl2T.png Where exactely does your problem appear? As far as I can see, you have the expression mentioned in your question introduced in the data driven override for the size of the label - does it appear anywhere else?

Comment: Yes, overrides are in a lot of places because setting a different rule-based for each variation would result in a lot of label types, making it difficult to modify whenever my boss want it to change. You are not seeing labels there, something went wrong. I edited my answer with another picture, in wich you can see how for 2 objects the label is placed centered instead of outside the polygon. Yesterday I didnt think about generating a symbology instead of a label to make the issue more visible

Comment: OK, now, I'm a little bit confused about what exactly the problem is and where the expression can be found that generates the problem...?

Comment: Last windows update totally screwed up my pc, cant even open calc files without getting a blue screen. I will be updating this as soon as I get someone with admin privileges to fix it